# Even/odd expressions

Tags: integers

Let's suppose that $\{a, b, c\}$ are distinct integers between $1$ and $9$. If we consider two real numbers with decimal representation $a,b$ and $c,b$ that sum up to an even integer, which of the expressions among $a+b+c$, $(a+c)c$, $ac+b$, or $(a+b)c$, and $abc$ can be argued certainly to be even or odd?

For $a,b+c,b = (a+\frac{b}{5})+(c+\frac{b}{10}) = (a+c)+\frac{2b}{10}$ to be an integer, one demands that $\frac{2b}{10}\in \mathbb{Z}$ which requires $2b = 10$ and $b = 5$.

$$a+c+1\equiv 0\pmod{2}\rightarrow a\equiv 1+c\pmod{2}$$

From which it holds immediately $a+b+c = a+c+5$ is even.

$$(a+c)c\equiv (1+2c)c \equiv c\pmod{2}$$

Which depends on $c$ being even or odd.

$$ac+b = ac+5\equiv (1+c)c+1 = c^2+c+1\pmod{2}$$

Which is always odd regardless of what $c$ is.

$$(a+b)c\equiv (c+2)c\equiv c^2\pmod{2}$$

Which depends on $c$ being even or odd.

$$abc = 5ac\equiv ac\equiv (1+c)c = c^2+c\pmod{2}$$

Which is always even regardless of what $c$ is.

Comment: $a,5+c,5$ will be $a+c+1$ not $a+c$.

Comment: Does “$a,b$” mean $a+\frac{b}{10}$ or something rlse?

Comment: @MJD Yes, $a, b = a+\frac{b}{10}$.

Comment: @David Thanks, edited

Comment: So are you wanting confirmation of your results? They are correct, as is your reasoning. You could determine it a bit more simply, but that is not a fault.